# Variable from another host in ansible

Tags: ansible

I don't understand why the domain-variable from localhost can't be found, even when dumping the full hostvars variable in the other host.

Here's the full playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    - domain: foo.com
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: domain
- hosts: "{{ host_ip }}"
  vars:
    - domain: "{{ hostvars.localhost.domain }}"
  tasks:
  - copy:
      content: "{{ hostvars }}"
      dest: facts.json
  - synchronize:
      mode: pull
      src: "./facts.json"
      dest: "../facts.json"
  - debug:
      var: hostvars.localhost.domain
  - debug:
      var: domain
```

I could understand if they were hidden under another host or something like that, but domain "foo.com" isn't in hostvars at all. I also tried with var: `hostvars['localhost']['domain']` but that made no difference

When run it's producing this output:

```
$ ansible-playbook -v -u docker --private-key '/home/mikael/.ssh/aws' -i '1.2.3.4,' -e ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3 /home/mikael/workspace/playbooks/vartest.yml --extra-vars 'host_ip=1.2.3.4'
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "domain": "foo.com"
}

PLAY [18.202.25.29] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [18.202.25.29]

TASK [copy] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [18.202.25.29]

TASK [synchronize] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [18.202.25.29]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [18.202.25.29] => {
    "hostvars.localhost.domain": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'domain'"
}

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [18.202.25.29] => {
    "domain": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'domain'"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
18.202.25.29               : ok=5    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0   
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'domain' variable is only persisting within the scope of the play it is specified in. This simply makes the variable available to the tasks in that play, but does not add it to the facts collection for each host in the play.

Instead add a task to the localhost play that adds a fact to the fact collection for localhost, which will be persisted beyond the play:

```
- name: Set domain variable
  set_fact:
    domain: foo.com
```

Comment: I thought registered variables and play variables were handled the same, but if I use register it's set as a fact?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your comment, but I think we talking at cross purposes. Registered variables, are those that are created to store the output of another module.  Facts are variables discovered about each system (or explicitly set with the set_fact command) and persist between plays. As for variable scope in general, the docs detail this: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables

Comment: Ah, yea those are what I mean. do stuff, register as foo. Thanks for the help :)